Motion of bowling ball
I'd like to model the motion of an asymmetric bowling ball thrown on a bowling lane. I know there's forward momentum and angular momentum that moment the ball is released, and there's of course gravity acting on the ball during its descent. But since the center of mass is not located in the balls geometric center, there will be some torque in its motion, encouraging the ball to spin along a certain axis.
My problem is I'm looking at three phases of the balls motion. There's the projectile phase, then as the ball hits the lane it encounters almost no friction due to the lane being coated with oil, so the ball will actually mostly glide. The final phase is when friction begins to act on the ball, which will force it to start rolling, and now that torque has more influence over its path.
Can anyone give me an idea how to put it all together? Or is anyone able to summarize that?

Here are a few items that you might find useful:

In terms of a reference, you might find reviewing something like Schaum's Theoretical Mechanics helpful:  https://archive.org/details/schaumsoutlineof0000spie_c9t5/page/252/mode/2up.   Chapter 9 and 10 discussing motion of rigid bodies might give some clues.  Schaum's usually provides concise explanations and a fair number of worked examples.

Breaking the problem into phases like you discuss seems a good idea.  Tackling each as a separate problem will probably be effective.

Try to start with simpler problems and build up.  Perhaps a symmetric disk first, followed by an asymmetric disk, then a symmetric ball, followed by an asymmetric ball, etc.

Consider limiting cases to make sure your solutions reduce to physically reasonable results at each point.  For example, have a completely friction-less bowling alley as one extreme vs. a bowling alley/ball that doesn't allow for slippage.


